# Azure - Add http listener to existing ApplicationGateway through ps command

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to add a new listener to existing Azure application gateway using powershell script. Here's the command I have used.

```
Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener -ApplicationGateway $Appgw -Name $listenerName -FrontendIPConfiguration $fipconfig -FrontendPort $port -SslCertificate $cert -HostName $hostName -Protocol "Https" -Debug
```

All the variables are correctly initialized. Command executes well and return ApplicationGateway object which seems normal. However the newly added listener is not visible in Azure portal. After watching carefully the new listener in ApplicationGateway object (in powershell) it just show below resource path,

```
/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/ResourceGroupNotSet/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/ApplicationGatewayNameNotSet/httpListeners/<new-listener-name>
```

two things doesn't seem normal here,

**ResourceGroupNotSet**

**ApplicationGatewayNameNotSet**

Can anyone please suggest what could be the reason behind this? and why the listener is not shown in portal at all?

Comment: How you tried to run the command ```Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw``` after you run the command```Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener```?

Comment: i didn't run this command. Not sure if it's there on documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my test, if we want to add HTTP listener to existing Azure Application gateway with Powershell, we need to run the command `Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw` after you run the command `Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener`. Because the command `Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener` just will create a new HTTP listener but it will not update the application gateway.

```
Connect-AzAccount

$AppGWname ="stantest"
$groupName="stan"
$ipName="appGwPublicFrontendIp"
$portName="port_80"
$listenerName="test1"


$appgw= Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name $AppGWname -ResourceGroupName $groupName
$FEC= Get-AzApplicationGatewayFrontendIPConfig -Name $ipName -ApplicationGateway $appgw



Add-AzApplicationGatewayFrontendPort -ApplicationGateway $appgw -Name $portName -Port 80
$port =Get-AzApplicationGatewayFrontendPort -ApplicationGateway $appgw -Name $portName


Add-AzApplicationGatewayHttpListener -ApplicationGateway $appgw -Name $listenerName -FrontendIPConfiguration $FEC -FrontendPort $port -Protocol Http

Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appgw
```

[image] 
[image]

Comment: running Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $Appgw  command actually solved this problem.